# Passing an object from imported module to a wrapped C++ function

Tags: c++, python, class, struct, swig

I have some C++ code which defines `struct A`. This is wrapped to create a python module. I have a separate C++ function which a part of `class B` in which I need to use an instance of `struct A` (passed by reference). This C++ code is also wrapped to be callable in python using swig. I want to call this function from `class B` in a python script.

In the run script, I import the module for `struct A`. However, when I create an instance of `struct A` in the run script, I am unable to pass it to the function from `class B`. The error I get is:

> `TypeError: in method '<function from class B>', argument 2 of type '<struct A> &'.`

Looks like `SWIG_ConvertPtr` is failing on the `struct A`. Do I need to do something extra for the wrapped `class B` code to "know" what `struct A` is?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you describe, ie no you don't have to do anything special, except perhaps if the two are defined in different modules. You'll have to show the code for .cpp, .i and .py.